# Something weird is happening when I try and insert data. Data will not insert

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a problem here. I have about 13K rows of data that I want to put into a mysql database. What I notice is that if the row is "short" the insert will happen but if it is long, it fails. I have been trying to figure this out all day and I'm about to give up.

Here is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `concordance` (
  `term` text NOT NULL,
  `ref` text NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is a row that will go in just fine.

```
"Abelmeholah"*"JDG 7:22 KI1 4:12 19:16"
```

Here is a large row that fails.

```
"A"*"GEN 6:16 30:11 EXO 4:2,26 12:45 28:34 30:2 38:26 39:26 LEV 20:27 21:14 25:11 NUM 28:21,29 29:10 DEU 2:21 8:8-9 9:2 11:12,27 22:30 23:2 26:5 28:50 JDG 9:54 13:6 KI2 11:5 CH2 23:4 PSA 22:30 37:16 68:5 74:5 91:7 92:1,6 97:3 101:4 107:34 112:5 PRO 1:5 6:12,17,19,33 9:13 10:1 11:1,13,16 12:2-4,8,10,14,16,23 13:1-2,5,17,22 14:5-6,16,25,30 15:1,4-5,12-13,18,20,23 16:9-11,28-29 17:2,4,8,10,17-18,22-23,25 18:2,6-7,16,19-20,24 19:5,9,13,19,24 20:8,26 21:14,22,28-29 22:1,3 24:5 25:11,18,26 26:3,28 27:3,12,15 28:3,17,20 29:5,11,19,23 30:30-31 ECC 3:2-8 6:2 7:1 10:2,14,19 SOL 1:13 4:12,15 ISA 8:12 21:2,8 27:2 42:3 60:22 62:12 65:3 66:6 JER 2:24 3:21 4:11 5:30 11:9,16 17:12 20:15 25:31,36 31:15,22 48:3 50:22,35-38 51:54 EZE 5:12 17:3 19:2 21:9 36:26 DAN 7:10 JOE 2:2-3 AMO 7:8 8:2 HAB 3:1 ZEP 1:16 MAL 1:6 MAT 5:14 7:18 11:7-9 12:20,35 13:57 16:4 21:28 MAR 6:4 12:1 LUK 2:24,32 6:45 7:24-26 8:5 10:30 13:6 14:16 15:11 19:12 20:9 JOH 1:42 3:27 9:11 13:34 16:16-19,21 19:36 ACT 3:22 7:37 10:2 11:5 CO1 7:15 GAL 5:9 TI1 3:2 TIT 3:10 HEB 8:2,13 JAM 1:8 REV 6:6"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Here is what I am using to get the data into the db

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/data.txt' 
INTO TABLE concordance 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '*'
```

---

I just tried loading the large dataset above and here is the error:
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.txt' INTO TABLE concordance FIELDS TERMINATED BY '*';
ERROR 1261 (01000): Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

---

**HERE IS THE CODE THAT WORKS:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/f.txt'
INTO TABLE `concordance`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '*'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
(`term` , `ref`);
```

Comment: what means the "*" sign ? and there's an error in your table structure - wrong primary key

Comment: Thanks, Actually, I changed the primary key from seq to id a little while ago. Good catch though. The "*" is the delimiter so when I import the data, the rows will split there.

Comment: i don't see the problem though.. can you post the code or commands you use to import data?

Comment: Thanks Kipelovets, I just posted it above in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table creation query is wrong:

```
#1072 - Key column 'seq' doesn't exist in table
```

Other than that, provided your query is ".... PRIMARY KEY (`id`) .... ", I can insert both lines of data without any problem. Maybe you should post your code.

---

Edit:

Try the following query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/data.txt' INTO TABLE `concordance` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '*'
    ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'(
    `term` , `ref` 
)
```

Comment: Thanks Anax. I changed it and it is still doing the same thing. The PK is not the problem. It is now id. I will make the changes above

Comment: That or the fact that you tell MySQL you only insert two out of three rows with local data.

Comment: Well, I even supplied the id column value and it failed. It is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

this command worked for me:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\xampp\tmp\php3BF.tmp' INTO TABLE `concordance` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '*' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

maybe you should provide value for `id` column too? or there is other error on line 1 in your file...

Comment: Thanks kipelovets, I'm not sure if there is an error on the first line or not but I believe that I need the lines terminated by '\r\n'. I don't understand why I need this though. Isn't it enough to use the ENCLOSED BY?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to ass a star at the end of each line, in order to tell MySQL that you want to skip the id field...

```
"Abelmeholah"*"JDG 7:22 KI1 4:12 19:16"*
```

It is strange though the short line goes in whereas the long line cannot..

Comment: I could try that as well. Honestly, I've never seen anything like this before. It is really strange. I will try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me on a windows system.  Have you tried escaping the commas in your text?